# Returning two AVX/AVX2 __m256d types in C++ function calls via registers

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, avx, calling-convention

I am new to programming with the AVX/AVX2 instructions and am trying to optimize the speed of my code. Following the older expectation that passing by reference is faster I wrote my code to do that but recently updated the code to pass by value to make use of fact that `__m256d` arguments would be passed into the function via the vector registers. When the function only passes out one result, the process below seems clear:

```
__m256d myfunc(const __m256d v1, const __m256d v2);
```

The latest [System V ABI for AMD64](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) alludes to the possibility that `%xmm0` AND `%xmm1` can be used for returning values.

So I assume `%ymm0` and `%ymm1` can be returned with AVX.
What is the calling method to pass back out two `__m256d` return values?  What C++ types will compile that way?

Comment: If you have a struct of two `double` values (or `float`), they will be returned via `xmm0`/`xmm1` (https://godbolt.org/z/zPexKT7zz). Maybe returning two `ymm` registers would make things complicated regarding compatibility with AVX512 (if you were returning something equivalent to `array<double,8>` should the compiler automatically put that into `zmm0` or `ymm0`+`ymm1`?)

Comment: I'm not sure that the ABI allows this.  In practice, I think you would either return a `struct` or return them by reference, whatever is more convenient, then make sure the called function can be inlined.  Then any apparent copies to/from memory can be optimized out and the values stay in registers anyway.  For similar reasons, it likely doesn't matter whether your C++ source has the arguments passed by value or by reference, since if inlining is possible, they will stay in registers regardless.

Comment: Page 23 of ABI says xmm0/xmm1: "used to pass and return floating point arguments". Since it also says xmm2-7 registers are used to pass floating point arguments, its as if xmm1 (and therefore presumably ymm1) can be used to return a floating point. @Nate do you have a reference on the statement, "since if inlining is possible, they will stay in registers regardless"? I am trying to keep as much of the variables in registers which is why I asked about returning thru xmm0/xmm1. If I pass by reference for the above: 
__m256d myfunc(__m256d v1, __m256d v2, __m256d &v3)
then v3 will be copied...

Comment: No official source, because no compiler ever *promises* to perform a particular optimization.  So when I say "they will" I mean "they probably will".   But from experience, it is an optimization that compilers are certainly capable of doing.  Once the called function is inlined, there is no difference between the code in the caller and the callee.  So passing or returning a value is effectively just an assignment, which any decent compiler can handle without moving anything, and certainly without going through memory.

Comment: In practice GCC and Clang does not use xmm1 nor ymm1 to store the return values while AFAIK they are supposed to implement this ABI on mainstream x86-64 platforms. As a result, I also do not think two registers can be returned with this ABI.

Comment: By copied, copied back to memory from register as in the ASM (godbolt.org/z/zPexKT7zz) has... @chtz, thanks for the example, it certainly shows consistency with the ABI (using both xmm0 and xmm1) for the simpler case of the double struct, but not for the __m256 struct!

Comment: @BigTuna: But what I'm saying is that if you can arrange that `foo` gets inlined into whatever function calls it, then the copies into memory will (almost certainly) not take place.  See for instance https://godbolt.org/z/dsrhT4j7d.  Yes, the out-of-line code for `minmax1` and `minmax2` shows copies into memory.  But when you look at the functions `absdiff1, absdiff2` that call them, there is no actual function call, no copies to/from memory, and both versions have identical optimal code.  The inefficient out-of-line code is never actually used.